# Get url id in php and check whether it exist or not in database

Tags: php, mysql, geturl

I have written code in php in order to get id from url and check whether it exists or not in mysql database. I have an existing value in the database but still getting a problem saying value is not found. Please anyone have a solution?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
      require 'Common.php';
      $Email=$_GET['id'];
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM cdcol.employees WHERE email='$Email'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0)

        {
            echo 'Email Found'; 
        }
    else
        {
        echo 'Email NOT Found';
        }
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the concatenate operator before the `mysql_real_escape_string($Email)`

Comment: I check the same mistake,but its still not coming..

Comment: What's the **actual** error message?

Comment: Use this.. `$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM cdcol.employees WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($Email)."'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 3):

Typo:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM cdcol.employees WHERE email='"mysql_real_escape_string($Email)"');
```

=>

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM cdcol.employees WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($Email)."'");
```

To improve the performance of this query, use `LIMIT 1` (you check if there is more than 0 lines):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM cdcol.employees WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($Email)."' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\mysql_ajax\url_check_email_blacklist.php on line 6 ......this is the error i ma getting

Comment: could you please post result of this: echo "SELECT email FROM cdcol.employees WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($Email)."'";

Comment: @AngularAddict, You still have a typo in the query ! You need to add a **double quote** at the end.

Comment: Hi i make changes in the code and i dont want mysql_real_string but its giving me the error Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\mysql_ajax\url_check_email_blacklist.php on line 6

Comment: Your query has an error and returns false (=boolean). Add `or die(mysql_error()); after the query to see the error

Comment: I made that changes still giving the same error Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\mysql_ajax\url_check_email_blacklist.php on line 6  ...I am using php 5.3 is that a problem of using mysql_num_rows ?

Comment: I am running the same query and its properly running in mysql database